# CUDA UVA copy failed

Tags: cuda

Here is the problem...
I tried to make a copy from host to host in my own vector container as the following code

```
T* data_t = 0;
size_t msize = sizeof(T) * capacity;
checkCudaErrors( cudaHostAlloc((void**)&data_t, msize, cudaHostAllocPortable) );

msize = sizeof(T) * count;
checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy(data_t, data, msize, cudaMemcpyDefault) ); 
//data is also allocated using cudaHostAlloc with flag cudaHostAllocPortable
```

I was be able to compile that code successfully using in my machine in my machine (with Ubuntu 10.04 64bit and my GPU GTX 590 and with CUDA 5.0) with this flag

> -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30

However when I tried to run it, it resulted an error in cuda with error message **invalid argument**

**Note:** Memory allocation with `cudaHostAlloc` is only temporary for test because I design my own container to be able to do copy from Host to Device or Host to Host automatically.

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem? Thank you.

**Update:**

I tried to use `cudaMemcpyHostToHost` the copy of memories (allocated as pinned memory with flag `cudaHostAllocPortable`) it worked only to a certain limit of memory size, after passed that limit, the copy will gave error message **segmentation fault**.

Comment: How is data allocated? Is it also registered with the CUDA driver?

Comment: data is also allocated using cudaHostAlloc with flag cudaHostAllocPortable

Comment: You haven't specified that the host memory will be mapped into the UVA address space. I think you need to add `cudaHostAllocMapped` to the flags in all `cudaHostAlloc`calls.

Comment: If UVA is in effect, all pinned allocations should be mapped and portable, regardless of whether those flags were specified.

Comment: @xnov: If both buffers are pinned memory (i.e. host memory), why are you calling a CUDA entry point to copy between them?

Comment: @talonmies it didn't work also when i put flag "cudaHostAllocPortable"  | cudaHostAllocMapped"

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware it just happened that i used pinned cpu memory. the code is intended to be able to do both cpu/gpu

Comment: @xnov I think you should provide a complete reproducer.  I created a simple app based on what you have shown here and had no problems even with `cudaMemcpyDefault`.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/mP3ukt5E) is my program and results.  SO expects: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance."  Voting to close -- you have not provided a SSCCE.org code